# How to join 4 tables for given keys (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery, inner-join

I have made a football database and now need to do some queries but need some advice:

So 4 tables:

- Players
- Managers
- Matches
- Teams

Need to pull results which display:

**Top 100 goal scorers**

Player(name) | Team(name) | Matches(goals) | Manager(name)

How would the code look like if:

- Players table contains; **playerid**, *managerid*, *teamid*, name
- Managers contains; **managerid**, name
- Matches contains; **matchid**, *playerid*, goals
- Teams contains; **teamid**, name

Right now I have something alone the lines of:

```
"SELECT players.name, teams.name, matches.goals, managers.name
          FROM players
          INNER JOIN ????
          ORDER BY matches.goals";
```

So what do I put within the INNER JOIN assuming everything else is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` to join the rows from *tables* `ON` *matching keys*.

- each `JOIN` combines the records of two tables
- `ON` specifies the columns that should match
- `INNER` means, join only where records match

Use `GROUP BY` to group (aggregate) your selected (joined) records.

- in the GROUP clause list all columns that should be grouped (different values in result only)
- in the *select-list* you can specify an optional *aggregated column* using an *aggregate-function*, like `SUM(goals)` to aggregate column `goals` as *sum*

The `ORDER BY` with a *column* (-list) and *direction* sorts the result-set (before limitting).

At the end the `LIMIT` keyword followed by a *number of results* cuts your result-set (suitable for TOP x queries). You may observe missing syntax-highlighting in formatted SQL code below. That's due to the fact that this limiting-keyword is not part of ANSI-SQL standard.

```sql
SELECT
  player.name as player,
  team.name as team,
  manager.name as manager,
  SUM(match.goals) as scored_goals
FROM Matches match
  INNER JOIN Players player ON match.playerid = player.playerid
  INNER JOIN Managers manager ON player.managerid = manager.managerid
  INNER JOIN Teams team ON player.teamid = team.teamid
ORDER BY match.goals DESC
GROUP BY player.name, team.name, manager.name
LIMIT 100;
```

**Note:** the aggregate `scored_goals` is the sum of all goals for a *specific combination*, that a given player has scored with the given team under given manager.

I added aliases with `as` for the columns (otherwise you could probably see multiple ambiguous labeled columns `name` in the output).

Answer (score 0):

You can join, and aggregate - or just join, and use a subquery to count the goals:

```
select p.name as player_name, t.name as team_name, m.name as manager_name, 
    (select sum(g.goals) from matches g where g.playerid = p.playerid) cnt_goals
from players p
inner join managers m on m.managerid = p.managerid
inner join teams t on t.teamid = p.teamid
order by cnt_goals desc limit 100
```

Comment: The _sub-selelect_ applied as easy add-on. Aliasing the result of SUM as `cnt_goals` here seems most naturally paraphrasing "count of goals"; not to be confused with frequently seen practice of prefixing COUNT results with 'cnt_' 

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.name, 
       T.name, 
       MA.goals, 
       M.name 
FROM   matches MA 
       INNER JOIN players P 
               ON MA.playerid = P.playerid 
       INNER JOIN managers M 
               ON P.managerid = M.managerid 
       INNER JOIN teams T 
               ON P.teamid = T.teamid 
ORDER  BY MA.goals DESC 
LIMIT  100;
```

Comment: Exactly answered the question. It may though contain duplicates since not made distint with `GROUP BY` 

Comment: Thanks for the comment @hc_dev, I did not notice the MYSQL tag, or the question was edited later. Thanks again.